# What does this variable do?

Tags: c++

> One day, Twilight Sparkle is interested in how to sort a sequence of
>   integers a1, a2, ..., an in non-decreasing order. Being a young
>   unicorn, the only operation she can perform is a unit shift. That is,
>   she can move the last element of the sequence to its beginning:
>
> a1, a2, ..., an → an, a1, a2, ..., an - 1.   Help Twilight Sparkle to
>   calculate: what is the minimum number of operations that she needs to
>   sort the sequence?
>
> Input
>   The first line contains an integer n (2 ≤ n ≤ 105). The second
>   line contains n integer numbers a1, a2, ..., an (1 ≤ ai ≤ 105).
>
> Output
>   If it's impossible to sort the sequence output -1. Otherwise
>   output the minimum number of operations Twilight Sparkle needs to sort
>   it.
>
> Examples
>   input
>   2
>   2 1
>   output
>   1
>   input
>   3
>   1 3 2
>   output
>   -1
>   input
>   2
>   1 2
>   output
>   0

Above is the problem and now I am confused because the solution down there used a variable called "s" and played around it for some reason but I don't know why was that variable used, if someone can tell me I'll be thankful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, s, v(0);
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> a(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> a[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) s = i, v++;
    if (a[n - 1] > a[0]) s = n - 1, v++;
    if (v == 0) cout << 0 << endl;
    else if (v > 1) cout << -1 << endl;
    else cout << n - 1 - s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now here is my own solution, it works and everything except on a 10^5(and around that) size array but the question time limit is only 1000 ms, and mine exceeds that limit due to the nested loops making it go over O(10^8) which is 1000 ms on their systems.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>


#define fl(i,n)    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)

#define ll   long long
#define nl   endl
#define pb   push_back
#define mp   make_pair
#define PII  pair<int,int>

#define EPS  1e-9
#define INF  1e9


using namespace std;

bool check(int a[], int n){
for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
    if(a[i] <= a[i+1]) continue;
    return false;
}
return true;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int a[n]; //is out of standard i know but it's accepted in the contest's compiler so we just use it
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    if(check(a,n)){
        cout << 0;
        return 0;
    }


    int ret = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        ret++;
        for(int j = n-1; j > 0; j--) 
        a[j] ^= a[j-1] ^= a[j] ^= a[j-1]; //is xor swap


        if(check(a,n)){
                cout << ret;
                return 0;
            }

    }
    cout << -1;



    return 0;
}
```

PS: I TRACED the solution's code and even if I get the correct answers I simply don't know what it refers to.

Comment: You should you your debugger.  With your debugger you can step through the code and observe what it is doing.  That would show you what `s` relates to in the array.

Comment: Don't learn from "competetive programming".

Comment: @NathanOliver I did trace it step by step and I get the right values, that's not what I wanted, I wanted to know what it REFERS to.

Comment: use proper indentation and read it again. Still face difficulty use GDB and watch variable.

Comment: @LogicStuff What's wrong with competitive programming ?

Comment: Guys..I did trace it. I don't want the values, I want what the 's' REFERS to...I also get it's obviously an index cause i is being assigned to it but what index is that?

Comment: Pick one question. Do you want to know what `s` is for in the other person's implementation, or do you want to improve the performance of your implementation?

Comment: @Kalcor... s denoting the iterations performed and n is total iteration

Comment: @underscore_d if you have an idea to improve the performance of the implementation over knowing what the s is it'll be alot better ofc

Comment: @someone but if it's denoting the number of iterations performed why do we use this condition "if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) s = i, v++;" this is just setting the current index value with the correct condition to s, for what?

Comment: @Kalcor "if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) s = i, v++;" here it is showing total number of swap. I hope you got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other person's implementation relies on an algorithmic insight.  The only way a sequence can be sorted by moving back to front is if the sequence is made of two already-sorted sections.  Then, the goal is to check how many unsorted discontinuities exist, and where they are.  That's what `s` appears to be used for: the index of the (last) discontinuity of the sequence.  `v` is the count of discontinuities.

If there are 0, it's already sorted.  If more than 1, it's unsortable.  If it's exactly one, then you can easily figure out how many shifts you need to perform to pull the discontinuity back to the front, using it's location (`s`) in the original sequence.

The only extra line of code is the special case of checking for the discontinuity around end of the sequence.

My recommendation: Generate a larger set of test sequences, and print `v` and `s` for each one.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: can you clearly explain the special case? this one : if (a[n - 1] > a[0]) s = n - 1, v++;

Comment: The loop checks `a[i] > a[i+1]`.  But the sequence is circular, so you also have to check the final number against the first number.  That's done in the special case: last (n-1) against first (0).  `s` and `v` are treated the same way if the condition is true: The index `s` is set to the index of last element, and `v` is incremented

Comment: yes but why is it circular? if i may ask. sorry for dumb questions q.q

Comment: Because you are allowed to move the back to the front.  Think about writing the sequence on a strip of paper taped in a circle.  The job of your program is to decide how many numbers to rotate the circle before cutting it again, so that the result is sorted.  That's why there can be only a single place where the numbers aren't sorted.  If you find the place where they're not sorted, cut there.  If there's more than one place, there's nothing you can do.